# setState is not working on object's object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to save some data in object's object, but its not working and its throwing me error.

This setState is not working.

I want to save some data in title and otherData.

```
 this.state = {
            data:{
                   title:" ",
                   otherData:" "
                 },
            size: "Medium",
            posterDiv: "700px",
            url: ArticlePoster,
            file: " ",
            base64: " "
        }
```

```
this.setSate({data.title:wantToSaveThisData})
```

but this setState is not working.

can anyone explain why my setState is not working

Comment: `this.setSate({data.title:wantToSaveThisData})` this line will not even compile. You can not put key like `data.title` in an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
this.setState({
  data: {
    ...this.state.data,
    title: wantToSaveThisData
  }
})
```

`...this.state.data` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), copying all of `this.state.data`'s props in the new state. The `title: wantToSaveData` will overwrite the previous `this.state.data.title`.

Comment: like you said spread syntax is copying all of data to new state. but i want to change not to copy so that i can use this.state.data.title in other function. please help @rateLess

Comment: can you explain why my setState is not working

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
this.setState({...this.state.data, title: wantToSaveThisData})
```

or

```
this.setState({...this.state, data:{ title: wantToSaveThisData}
```

Comment: can you explain why my setState is not working-@VahidAkhtar

Answer (score 0):

You need do it properly without state mutations:

```
  this.state = {
            data:{
                   title:" ",
                   otherData:" "
                 },
            size: "Medium",
            posterDiv: "700px",
            url: ArticlePoster,
            file: " ",
            base64: " "
        }
 const newData = {title:"New Title",otherData:"Other Data"}
 
 this.setState({...this.state, data:newData);
```